# Ruby variable initialisation

Tags: ruby, variables

In the following code there is an execution path where "bar" is not set before it is tested, is doing this safe in Ruby? will "bar" have a default initialisation?

```
if foo
  bar = true
end

if bar
  puts "true"
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes

**Yes**, it is safe, in the sense that the worst that can happen when an uninitialized local is referenced is that a **NameError** exception will be raised.

Yours is a bit of a special-case, actually. Since the parser will have seen `bar` before it is referenced, then the method will *not* raise `NameError`, even if `foo` is false, but rather the value of `bar` will be `nil`.

Comment: To be more explicit, `if` doesn't introduce a new scope in ruby.  So the `bar` variable is introduced in the environment.

Comment: So in my above example, what would bar contain if the first conditional was bypassed?

Comment: when the `foo` conditional is false: `nil`